# NTLM Authentication Android Studio

Tags: java, android, authentication, android-studio, ntlm

I've spent many hours trying to figure out how to perform NTLM authentication on Android Studio with no luck. I realize NTLM is not native to Android. Recently, I have been using the JCIFS library

```
jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
URL url = new URL("https://domain%5cuser:pass@host");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

But I have getting the error

```
"Unable to find default handler for protocol: https"
```

The same code works in standard Java. At this point I've exhausted every suggestion I have found and I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm attempting to resolve the same issue, and came across the following link (class is pasted below in case of link rot): 
https://lists.samba.org/archive/jcifs/2013-July/010105.html

I then use the following to force the handler's use:

```
    jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();

    System.setProperty("http.auth.ntlm.domain", domain);
    System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.domain", domain);
    System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.username", username);
    System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.password", password);
    System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "domain.com.package");
```

I'm having issues, however, as the response comes back empty, so more investigation needs to be done there.

(The copyright notice, etc. have been left off as it kept confusing SO's code block parser)

```
public class Handler extends URLStreamHandler {
/**
 * The default HTTP port (<code>80</code>).
 */
public static final int DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT = 80;

private static final Map PROTOCOL_HANDLERS = new HashMap();

private static final String HANDLER_PKGS_PROPERTY =
        "java.protocol.handler.pkgs";

/**
 * Vendor-specific default packages.  If no packages are specified in
 * "java.protocol.handler.pkgs", the VM uses one or more default
 * packages, which are vendor specific.  Sun's is included below
 * for convenience; others could be as well.  If a particular vendor's
 * package isn't listed, it can be specified in
 * "java.protocol.handler.pkgs".
 */
private static final String[] JVM_VENDOR_DEFAULT_PKGS = new String[] {
    "sun.net.www.protocol"
};

private static URLStreamHandlerFactory factory;

/**
 * Sets the URL stream handler factory for the environment.  This
 * allows specification of the factory used in creating underlying
 * stream handlers.  This can be called once per JVM instance.
*
 * @param factory The URL stream handler factory.
 */
public static void setURLStreamHandlerFactory(
        URLStreamHandlerFactory factory) {
    synchronized (PROTOCOL_HANDLERS) {
        if (Handler.factory != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "URLStreamHandlerFactory already set.");
        }
        PROTOCOL_HANDLERS.clear();
        Handler.factory = factory;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the default HTTP port.
 *
 * @return An <code>int</code> containing the default HTTP port.
 */
protected int getDefaultPort() {
    return DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
}

@Override
protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException
{
    return this.openConnection(url, null);
}

@Override
protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url, Proxy proxy) throws IOException
{
    url = new URL(url, url.toExternalForm(), getDefaultStreamHandler(url.getProtocol()));

    final HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    if (proxy == null) {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } else {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
    }

    return new NtlmHttpURLConnection(urlConnection);
}

private static URLStreamHandler getDefaultStreamHandler(String protocol)
        throws IOException {
    synchronized (PROTOCOL_HANDLERS) {
        URLStreamHandler handler = (URLStreamHandler)
                PROTOCOL_HANDLERS.get(protocol);
        if (handler != null) return handler;
        if (factory != null) {
            handler = factory.createURLStreamHandler(protocol);
        }
        if (handler == null) {
            String path = System.getProperty(HANDLER_PKGS_PROPERTY);
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(path, "|");
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String provider = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
                if (provider.equals("jcifs")) continue;
                String className = provider + "." + protocol + ".Handler";
                try {
                    Class handlerClass = null;
                    try {
                        handlerClass = Class.forName(className);
                    } catch (Exception ex) { }
                    if (handlerClass == null) {
                        handlerClass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(
                                ).loadClass(className);
                    }
                    handler = (URLStreamHandler) handlerClass.newInstance();
                    break;
                } catch (Exception ex) { }
            }
        }
        if (handler == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < JVM_VENDOR_DEFAULT_PKGS.length; i++) {
                String className = JVM_VENDOR_DEFAULT_PKGS[i] + "." +
                        protocol + ".Handler";
                try {
                    Class handlerClass = null;
                    try {
                        handlerClass = Class.forName(className);
                    } catch (Exception ex) { }
                    if (handlerClass == null) {
                        handlerClass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(
                                ).loadClass(className);
                    }
                    handler = (URLStreamHandler) handlerClass.newInstance();
                } catch (Exception ex) { }
                if (handler != null) break;
            }
        }
        if (handler == null) {
            throw new IOException(
                    "Unable to find default handler for protocol: " +
                            protocol);
        }
        PROTOCOL_HANDLERS.put(protocol, handler);
        return handler;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Still working on it; I moved the Handler and the test class into a Java library module. Instead of a null response stream I'm now getting back a 401.